# How do I get `make` to prompt the user for a password and store it in a Makefile variable?

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm writing a Makefile, and some of the commands the makefile runs require a password.  I'd like to give the user the ability to either pass this in as a Makefile variable using `make PASSWORD=password` or if the user does not pass it in, then prompt the user for it and store their response in said Makefile variable.

At the moment, I'm able to check the Makefile variable, and then as part of my target specific rules, write shell commands that prompt the user for the password and store it in a shell variable.  However, this variable is only available to that specific shell and not any others.

How do I read something from the user and store it in a variable?

I've tried the following:

```
PASSWORD ?= $(shell read -s -p "Password: " pwd; echo $pwd)
```

but the prompt is never printed.  I've also tried `echo "Password: "` inside shell, but that isn't printed either.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

To clarify, the password needs to be set for a specific target, so I have something like this:

```
PASSWORD := 

my-target: PASSWORD ?= $(shell read -s -p "Password: " pwd; echo $$pwd)

my-target:
    # rules for mytarget that use $(PASSWORD)
```

**Edit 2:**

I found the problem.  When I set `PASSWORD :=` at the top of the script, it sets `PASSWORD` to an empty string, and this in turn causes the `?=` to be skipped (since `PASSWORD`) is already set.

Comment: What command needs a password?  ssh?  Could you use ssh-passwordless login instead? http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Comment: no, not ssh.  I need to run curl 3 times against a service that requires authentication.  curl can prompt for its own password, but I'd rather not force the user to enter it 3 times.

Comment: I feel like plaintext passwords in Make variables may be vulnerable to exploitation.  I'm not sure how to exploit it, but it might be easy for a malicious user dump the makefile variables (make -pn) and get this password.  Just sayin' ;-)

Comment: That user would be the same user running make and entering the password, unless a different user could gain access to the memory space of a command run by the first user... in that case, all bets are off and your OS is completely compromised.

Comment: Yes, if its a `curl` password, I don't know of any other way to deal with it than what you are doing.  I guess the worst case scenario I'm worried about is someone needs to debug your Makefile in the future and dumps `make -pn` logs to disk somewhere.  Then the malicious user would see the plaintext password in the build log.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A couple of things:

- the `$` for dereferencing shell variable `pwd` is being interpreted by `make`.  You can escape it from make with `$$`
- `make` is invoking the shell as Posix compatible `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.  As such, the `-s` option to `read` is not supported.

Try this instead:

```
PASSWORD ?= $(shell bash -c 'read -s -p "Password: " pwd; echo $$pwd')
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 / GNU make 3.81 / bash 4.2.25(1)

And on OSX 10.8.5 / make 3.81 / bash 3.2.48(1):

```
$ cat Makefile 
PASSWORD ?= $(shell bash -c 'read -s -p "Password: " pwd; echo $$pwd')

all:
    echo The password is $(PASSWORD)
$ make
Password: echo The password is 1234
The password is 1234
$
```

---

Update - @user5321531 pointed out that we can use POSIX `sh` instead of `bash`, and temporarily suppress echo with `stty`:

```
PASSWORD ?= $(shell stty -echo; read -p "Password: " pwd; stty echo; echo $$pwd)
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work on MacOSX / GNU Make 3.81 / bash 3.2.48.  It refuses to print the prompt.

Comment: @bluesmoon - it seems to work the same on OSX as Ubuntu for me.  Perhaps I'm missing something?  I've added my test Makefile and console log to the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see the difference.  I need the variable set for a specific target only.  I'll edit the question with an example.

Comment: Ok, I now see my problem.  I was initializing PASSWORD to an empty string at the top of my Makefile, so it was skipping the `?=` part entirely.

Thanks for your comments.  The $$pwd was the other thing I missed.

Comment: A quick comment, if using a POSIX shell, to prevent echo to screen `stty -echo` and to re-enable `stty echo`.

Comment: Quick question, how do you get `make` to not ask for the password multiple times if it's used in more than one location?

Comment: @joeb please see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61948795/1979230

Comment: `SHELL := /bin/bash`, usually near the top of your Makefile, will force make to use bash rather than the default sh.

Answer (score 3):

To answer @joeb 's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671511/how-do-i-get-make-to-prompt-the-user-for-a-password-and-store-it-in-a-makefile#comment100885022_20671804), you can make `make` only ask for the password once and use it multiple times with `define` as in:

```
all: first second

PASSWORD ?= $(shell read -s -p "Password: " pass; echo $$pass)

define formatted
first:
        @echo $1
second:
        @echo $1
endef

$(eval $(call formatted,$(PASSWORD)))
```

Usage then looks like:

```
Password: <hidden>
mypassword
mypassword
```

Comment: I think I found a simpler way with `:=`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78161577/895245

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com yeah, that's better. Anyone visiting this in the future should use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Ask for the password only once and use it multiple times with `:=`**

If you use `=` or `?=` then it asks multiple times, but with `:=` it evaluates immediately, e.g.:

```
PASSWORD := $(shell read -s -p "Password: " pass; echo $$pass)

all: nothing
    @echo all: $(PASSWORD)

nothing:
    @echo nothing: $(PASSWORD)
```

then `make` gives:

```
Password: nothing: <password>
all: <password>
```